# XSLT 1: XPath - select/extract a number from a string, with default value

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I'm transforming a document using the XSL engine provided by out-of-the-box Java 6.

I need to grab a value from an attribute, and use it as an index attribute in a document I am transforming to.

For example, the element:

```
<myElem bogen="K [1]"/>
```

the attribute 'bogen' may have values:

"K [1]"
"K [2]"
up to 'n' values. 
It may also simply have 
"K" to indicate the same as "K [1]"

the corresponding transformation result (from "K [1]" would look like this:

```
<myTransformedElem index="1"/>
```

I could use the transformation:

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate(@bogen,translate(@bogen, '0123456789', ''), '')"/>
```

if it were just values expected as "K [1]".
But where there is the possibility of having no actual number included, such as "K", this stuffs me up.

The only way I can do it is if I abuse the 'number' function, expect a 'NaN' and translate that. Which seems exceedingly ugly.

For example:

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate(string(number(translate(@bogen,translate(@bogen, '0123456789', ''), ''))), 'aN', '1')"/>
```

gets me the correct result each time.

Is there a better, nicer way to do this in XSLT without resorting to custom methods (i.e., import static java methods) ?

For example; were I to need a default value of a multi-character string, I couldn't use the above solution.

thanks in advance.

sean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with this XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="myElem">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="translate(@bogen, '0123456789', '') != @bogen">
                <myTransformedElem index="{translate(@bogen,translate(@bogen, '0123456789', ''), '')}"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <myTransformedElem index="1"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to this XML:

```
<root>
    <myElem bogen="K"/>
</root>
```

produces

```
<myTransformedElem index="1"/>
```

and when applied to this XML:

```
<root>
    <myElem bogen="K [2]"/>
</root>
```

produces

```
<myTransformedElem index="2"/>
```

Comment: Great! Thanks, to both solutions, from you Joel, and JLRishe. Too bad one can't click two answers as being "accepted".

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to do this:

```
  <xsl:template name="GetIndex">
    <xsl:param name="value" />
    <xsl:param name="default" select="1" />

    <xsl:variable name="foundIndex"
                  select="substring-before(
                             substring-after($value, '['), ']')" />
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$foundIndex">
        <xsl:value-of select="$foundIndex"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$default"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
```

This call produces the value `1`:

```
<xsl:call-template name="GetIndex">
  <xsl:with-param name="value" select="'K[1]'" />
</xsl:call-template>
```

This call produces the value `37`:

```
<xsl:call-template name="GetIndex">
  <xsl:with-param name="value" select="'K[37]'" />
</xsl:call-template>
```

This call produces the value `1`:

```
<xsl:call-template name="GetIndex">
  <xsl:with-param name="value" select="'K'" />
</xsl:call-template>
```

This call produces the value `999`:

```
<xsl:call-template name="GetIndex">
  <xsl:with-param name="value" select="'K'" />
  <xsl:with-param name="default" select="999" />
</xsl:call-template>
```

If you find the `xsl:choose` to be too verbose, you can rewrite `GetIndex` like this and get the same results:

```
  <xsl:template name="GetIndex">
    <xsl:param name="value" />
    <xsl:param name="default" select="1" />

    <xsl:variable name="foundIndex"
                  select="substring-before(
                             substring-after($value, '['), ']')" />

    <xsl:value-of select="concat($foundIndex, 
                                 substring($default, 1, 
                                           not($foundIndex) * 
                                           string-length($default)))"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

Personally, I think the version with `xsl:choose` is clearer, even if it is longer.

Comment: Thank you very much. A useful solution, which I did not think of.